# undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby

While creating a bubble sort program i ran into this error:

```
test.rb:8:in `block in bubble_sort': undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from test.rb:6:in `downto'
    from test.rb:6:in `bubble_sort'
    from test.rb:16:in `<main>
```

does anyone know what does that mean? Here is the code:

```
def bubble_sort(arr)
    length = arr.length
    sorted = false


    length.downto(0) do |cntr|

        if arr[cntr] < arr[cntr + 1]

        end


    end
end

bubble_sort([2,6,8,1,0,2])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message `undefined method '<' for nil:NilClass` means that you are trying to call `<` on something that is `nil`.

In your example that must be the `if arr[cntr] < arr[cntr + 1]` comparison. In a next step we need to find out why `arr[cntr]` is `nil`. One reason could be that there is no element in the `arr` array at the `cntr` index, another reason might be that the index `cntr` is out of bounds of the array. In your example it is the second reason that is causing the problem.

Why is the index out of bounds? Let's have a closer look how the loop is build and use an example array `[a, b, c]` to do so:

```
length = arr.length              # length = 3             # [a, b, c].length
length.downto(0) do |cntr|       # 3.downto(0) do |cntr|
  if arr[cntr] < arr[cntr + 1]   #   if arr[3] < arr[4]   # in the first iteration
```

Ops, there aren't not indexes `3` and `4` in the `arr` array, because indexes start counting with `0` and there are only 3 elements in my example (that makes the last element's index `2`).

The fix:

```
def bubble_sort(array)
  (array.length - 2).downto(0).each do |index|
    if array[index] < array[index + 1]
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 2):

> does anyone know what does that mean?

It means that `arr[cntr]` is nil in this expression

```
if arr[cntr] < arr[cntr + 1]
```

Oh, and if this one is nil, then `arr[cntr + 1]` is **definitely** nil.

Hint: you're accessing elements out of bounds of the array.

Comment: why is arr[0] out of bound? there clearly is something there

Comment: Why do you think it's 0?

Comment: ...as stated in the doc for [Array#[\]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D).

Answer (score 0):

In your code `length` variable value will be `6`(`length = arr.length`).
When you iterate it down to `0` ... in the first iteration `cntr` variable value will be `6`.
so `arr[cntr]` is getting `nil` value because you are accessing elements out of bounds of the array. That's why you are getting `undefined method < for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)` error.